# Spring boot properties to object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following config

```
job:
  x:
    cron: 0 0 0 1,16 * ?
    group: xg
    name: xn
  y:
    cron: 0 0 1 1,16 * ?
    group: yg
    name: yn
```

and a JAVA POJO like this

```
public class JobConfigProperties {
    private String group;
    private String name;
    private String cron;
    ...
}
```

> I am looking for a way to let spring boot populate those classes
>
> @LoadPropertiesAsObject(prefix="job.x") private JobConfigProperties
>   jobXConfig; @LoadPropertiesAsObject(prefix="job.y") private
>   JobConfigProperties jobYConfig;

`@ConfigurationProperties` is not working because it must be attached to a class or a method

Later edit: it seems that `@ConfigurationProperties` can be applied on a method. I will give it a try and come back with the result.

Answer (score 3):

You can add dynamic properties by a map in your configuration class. The key has to be a string (the property key) and the value can be a complex class with multiple variables.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("job")
public class JobConfigProperties {

  private Map<String, Intern> values;

  public Map<String, Intern> getValues() {
    return values;
  }
  public void setValues(Map<String, Intern> values) {
    this.values = values;
  }

  public static class Intern {

    private String cron;
    private String group;
    private String name;

    public String getCron() {
      return cron;
    }

    public void setCron(String cron) {
      this.cron = cron;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
      return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
      this.group = group;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

  }

}
```

In your example you have to put a "values" element between "job" and your dynamic variables:

```
job:
  values: 
    x:
      cron: 0 0 0 1,16 * ?
      group: xg
      name: xn
    y:
      cron: 0 0 1 1,16 * ?
      group: yg
      name: yn
```

Hope it helps...